# Why we can not directly pass the asp.net controls id as javascript function argument?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonId" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="check(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>'))"/>
```

**Why we can not use the above code to pass the TextBox1 Id to javascript function?**

```
ButtonId.OnClientClick = string.Format("check('{0}')", TextBox1.ClientID);
```

**What is use of the above code in Page_Load?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClientId` is the ID of control rendered into the browser, and may or may not be the same as your control's ID (i.e. server side ID). That's why the best practice is to use either the control's `ClientId` property or some sort of JavaScript way to get it, (usually relative to where you need it, e.g. using `this` or `this.parent` or `getElementById` etc.)

The `ClientId` will be different than the`ID` property when the control is nested into another container. In such cases the parent control's ID is prepended with the control ID to make the `ClientId` property.

Comment: i Want to know what is use of "string.Format()" method.

Comment: And why we are not able to sent ClientId to javascript function directly by adding OnClientClick="check(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>'))"

Comment: It will work. The trick is to put single quotes where you have put double quotes and vice-versa. i.e. `OnClientClick='check(document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>"))'`. It is more related to escaping properly than anything else.

Comment: Regarding `String.Format`, it is just an elegant way of concatenating strings properly. It is effectively same as `"check('" & Textbox1.ClientId & "')"`